# Inverse Laplace transform of function with square roots.

Tags: laplace-transform, bessel-functions

Let $F\colon \mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ be defined as $$F(s) = \frac{1}{2+s+\sqrt{4s+s^2}}.$$  My question is, what is the inverse Laplace transform of $F$?  From solving similar problems I have a feeling that Bessel functions are involved.  My first guess would be $f(t) = \exp(-2t)J_0(2t)$, but that is incorrect.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** the inverse Laplace transform of:
$$ f(s) = \frac{1}{s+\sqrt{s^2-4}}=\frac{s-\sqrt{s^2-4}}{4} $$
is given by:

> $$ (\mathcal{L}^{-1} f)(x) = \color{red}{\frac{I_1(2x)}{2x}}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^{2n}}{n!(n+1)!}\tag{1} $$

where $I_1$ is a [modified Bessel function of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function), and it is probably easier to show that the Laplace transform of the RHS of $(1)$ is $f(s)$ by exploiting the Taylor series of $I_1$ and the generalized binomial theorem / [the generating function for Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number). From $(1)$ it follows that:

> $$ (\mathcal{L}^{-1} F)(t) = \color{red}{\frac{I_1(2t)}{2t}e^{-2t}}\tag{2} $$

Comment: Hi, just an FYI.  I am writing to let you know that I have posted a new similar question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1837207/another-laplace-transform-of-a-function-with-square-roots.  I hope you might be able to look at it.  Thanks!