# Another Laplace transform of a function with square roots.

Tags: special-functions, laplace-transform

This question is very much related to this ([one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1833597/inverse-laplace-transform-of-function-with-square-roots%22%20one.)).

Let $F\colon \mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ be defined as 
$$F(s) = \frac{1}{4+3s+\sqrt{s(4+s)}}.$$  My question is what is the inverse Laplace transform of $F$?  Like the previous link, I suspect that it has something to to with Bessel functions.  I have used Mathematica in a trial and error process and haven't made any progress.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have:

$$G(s)=F(s-2) = \frac{1}{3s-2+\sqrt{s^2-4}} $$
so, in order to tackle this problem like the previous one, we should find the coefficients of the Taylor series at $x=0$ of:
$$ H(x) = G\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = \frac{x}{3-2x+\sqrt{1-4x^2}}=\sum_{n\geq 1}g_n x^n\tag{1} $$
to deduce (have also a look at [Ramanujan's master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%27s_master_theorem)):
$$ (\mathcal{L}^{-1}G)(t) = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{g_n t^{n-1}}{(n-1)!},\qquad (\mathcal{L}^{-1} F)(t)=e^{-2t}\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{g_{n+1} t^n}{n!}\tag{2}$$
The main issue here is that while the Taylor coefficients of $\frac{x}{1-\sqrt{1-4x^2}}$ are pretty easy to find in terms of Catalan numbers, the coefficients $g_n$ appearing in $(1)$ and $(2)$ are a bit more involved.

Moreover, $H(x)$ has two singularities located at $\frac{3\pm i\sqrt{7}}{4}$, hence the RHS of $(2)$ is expected to converge (much) slower than the Taylor series of a Bessel function.

Comment: So nice..... +1

Comment: Is there a good book or article about Ramanujan's master theorem?